# What software can I use to simulate cellular connection

Tags: bandwidth, testing, simulation

We need to do some stress testing of our system, and we would like to be able to simulate non-ideal situations: things like latency, jitter, etc. In particular, we would like to simulate behavior of data over a cellular network.

Do you know of any hardware/software/both solutions that would work?

Thanks

Comment: which OS are you testing from?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would get some idea about parametrization from a real simulator like `ns3`. Or write one yourself.

Additionally you could use the Linux kernels built-in QoS stack which provides the `netem` module which can be used for these purposes. `netem` provides network emulation functionality for testing protocols by emulating the properties of wide area networks. The current version emulates variable delay (jitter), loss, packet corruption, duplication and re-ordering. It supports distribution based opteration or you could script it to change certain values during run time.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi card with an older access point/router, simply take the test station to the edge of the range and you should be able to reliably cause the connection to fail and reconnect. Only reason I sugest an older model is that the range generally weren't that fantastic on the older "802.11b" stuff.

But other than just being a lossy connection, I am not sure you'd be able to use this setup to test certain characteristics of a cellular connection, but it should work.

If you are in the US, an iPhone on AT&T would probably do it..

Answer (score 1):

Probably need something along the lines of:

USRP Board, OpenBTS, TrixBox/Asterisk

You can check out OpenBTS(http://openbts.sourceforge.net/) and see if it will do what you need.  You could have it use the USRP board as a tower, then use it similar to a loopback.  I do know that the above combination will allow phones to connect to it like a cell tower(See BurningMan/DEFCON 18), so in theory it should allow you to broadcast out to saturate the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

OpenBTS-UMTS include 3G data http://openbts.org/w/index.php?title=OpenBTS-UMTS
You can download and compile on Ubuntu 16.04, there is some issue with dependencies on Ubuntu 18.04.
About hardware, i used both Ettus USRP N210 and X310.